# named parameter in Dart

Tags: dart, dart-null-safety

Good day, I am trying to apply named parameter {num phone} to the below example:

```
main(){

showInfo("abc@mail.com", "Fatima");
}

String showInfo(String email, String name, {num phone}) {
print(email);
print(name);
print(phone);
return "$email : $name : $phone";
}
```

but I receive the error:

```
Error: The parameter 'phone' can't have a value of 'null' because of its type 'num', but the implicit 
default value is 'null'.
Try adding either an explicit non-'null' default value or the 'required' modifier.
Future<String> showInfo(String email, String name, {num phone}) async {
                                                     ^^^^^
```

your help is appreciated.

Comment: Dart has introduced null safety. It's an awesome feature, but it meant breaking changes. Make sure the books an tutorials you are using are aware of that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You marked the parameter as a `num`, which means it cannot be `null`. However, the default for named parameters that are not used is `null`, so you cannot have a named parameter that is optional with a default value of `null` with a datatype that does not accept `null`.

One option is to give it a default value *other* than `null`:

```
String showInfo(String email, String name, {num phone = 0})
```

Another option is to make it a named, **but required** parameter, so it will never get a default value:

```
String showInfo(String email, String name, {required num phone})
```

Another alternative is to actually keep the phone optional:

```
String showInfo(String email, String name, {num? phone})
```

Some additional wisdom: phone numbers can start with leading zeroes that are important and should not be deleted on saving it. You cannot use `num` for a phone number, you will have to use `string`.

Comment: Depends on what you want to do with the default value. I added another option I forgot: you can *keep* it optional.

Answer (score 0):

The error is pretty clear, you have to pass a value to the `phone` parameter or add a default value. This is due to the introduction of [Null Safety](https://dart.dev/null-safety/understanding-null-safety) in Dart 2.12.

You can pass a value like this :

```
showInfo("abc@mail.com", "Fatima", phone: 0);
```

Or add a default value to the `phone` parameter :

```
String showInfo(String email, String name, {num phone = 0}) {
   print(email);
   print(name);
   print(phone);
   return "$email : $name : $phone";
}
```

If you want, you can use Dart <2.12 to avoid Null Safety, your code should work properly then.

Comment: in a tutorial someone did it exactly like mine and it printed "null" for phone parameter.

Comment: Which version of Dart are you using ? Since 2.12, Dart introduced null safety (https://dart.dev/null-safety/understanding-null-safety), that's what gives you the error.

Comment: In `pubspec.yaml` you can set the Dart version to `>= 2.0.0 && < 2.12.0`